# boxing through casting interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, casting, boxing

If I have an interface A and inherited class B:

```
interface A { }
class B : A { }
```

and write this:

```
B sth = new B();
A aaa = B;
B bbb = (B)aaa;
```

will there occur any boxing?
Of course, A and B are not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxing only occurs with value types. `B` is a reference type, so no, there is no boxing.

If `B` were a value type (`struct` instead of `class`), then yes, boxing would occur.

```
interface IA { }
struct B : IA { }

B b = new B();
IA a = b; //boxing, converting a value type into a reference type
b = (B)a; //unboxing, converting a boxed value type back to the value type itself
```

One way to avoid these boxing and unboxing operations when dealing with structs and interfaces is defining a generic interface, a la `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable<T>`, etc., which enables you to *work* with the interface without actually boxing the value type itself.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) is more.